# The Label breaking with character - automatically in Redmi Note 4 device

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, label

I'm trying to display a label in my Redmi not Device. But the word is breaking with **-** at the end. I want the whole word to be displayed in next line instead of breaking the word. For example

> Welcome to Lighthouse, the PSAV online customer followup **prog-**
>
> **ram** designed to ensure a one-on-one approach to individual guest contact and interaction. **Lo-**
>
> **gin** using your PSAV credentials to begin entering your guests' Touch Points now.

It should be:

> Welcome to Lighthouse, the PSAV online customer followup
>
> **program** designed to ensure a one-on-one approach to individual guest contact and interaction.
>
> **Login** using your PSAV credentials to begin entering your guests' Touch Points now.

But this is not shown in any other device rather than Redmi Note 4. I have **tried all LineBreakMode properties** but nothing helps. This is my code

```
 <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Margin="10" x:Name="lblLogin" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding lblLoginText , Mode=TwoWay}" > </Label>
```

I know I can use `&#x0a;` with the word which breaks and it will take that word to next line. But that is like hard coding a break line . I want it to be done dynamically.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer I have mentioned clearly I have tried all LineBreakMode properties but nothing helps in my question.Also I have answered my question as well. Yes I'll make sure not to use chatty material in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have fixed. It was a simple Issue my label was running out of space so I increased the space using WidthRequest. I have put `WidthRequest="328"` which is solving my word break issue.If anyone is suggesting me the fix using custom label renderer you are welcome.